# What is the name for the instrument to measure radiation consisting mainly out of a glass ball?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, sun, instrument

I remember vaguely a measurement instrument to protocol probably [solar irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance). The instrument mainly consisted out of a glass sphere and if I recall correctly, the sun was "writing" lines on thermopaper. The main component was a (solid?) Glas Ball which worked as a lens and then there probably some optics and mechanics around, including a place where you would put a paper on which lines of different gray Tones would appear. I am not sure whether it Server astronomical or metereological purposes.

May you help me how that instrument is called, please?

Answer (score 1):

that device was probably called a *solar radiometer*.